# How can a form accept only a particular data type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So I have a form that gets student ID and Name, stores it in a JSO file then displays it automatically when a button is clicked .
But now I want the form to filter the response of the students such that a student can only enter integers for the id and string for the name

```
async function addStudent() {
    const url = server + '/students';
    const student = {id: studentId, name: studentName};
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(student)
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
}
```

I tried googling everywhere but I couldn't find anything

Comment: You are doing this on the server as well, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your button is pressed, I would have your values be checked before going through your post request. Something formatted like the following:

```
if (isNaN(form.studentId.value) && !(isNaN(form.name.value))) {
    addStudent();
} else {
    alert("Invalid form!");
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful especially with StudentID but when it comes to the name It doesn't work, but thank you at least the ID is now verified